# Function returns -1.#IND00 + merging functions

Tags: c, function, pointers

so i'm basically trying to merge following 3 functions in 1 (thats what my teacher wants, but i couldnt get it to work so i did 3)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TOTAL_DEG  (180.0)


double berechnung_length(double a, double b, double c, double gamma)
{   
    c = sqrt(a * a + b * b - (2 * a * b * cos(gamma)));
    return c;
}

double berechnung_alpha(double a, double b, double c, double gamma, double alpha)
{
    alpha = gamma * acos((double )(b * b + c * c - a * a) / (2.0 * b * c));
    return alpha;
}

double berechnung_beta(double gamma, double alpha, double beta)
{
    beta = - gamma - alpha + TOTAL_DEG;
     return beta;
}
```

soo, how can i get the function to return the values if its just 1 function (pointers would be an option but im not so comfy with them yet)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: what about building a struct with c, alpha and beta and working with a pointer to the struct.

Comment: Note: `acos((double )(b * b + c * c - a * a) / (2.0 * b * c));` is a problem when the quotient is close to 1.0, -1.0.  Due to `double` math details, sometimes the  result is  just over 1.0 or under -1.0, even though the mathematical answer would not allow that.

Comment: `acos()` returns _radians_.  `alpha + TOTAL_DEG` likely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> to merge following 3 functions in 1

Using OP's existing function calls:

```
void berechnung_all(double a, double b, double c, double gamma,
    double *length, double *alpha, double *beta) {
  *length = berechnung_length(a,b,c,gamma);
  *alpha = berechnung_alpha(a,b,c,gamma, 0);
  *beta = berechnung_beta(a,b,c,gamma, *alpha, 0);
}
```

---

Tighter integration

```
#ifndef M_PI
#define M_PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795
#endif

#define R2D(r) ((r)*180.0/M_PI)
#define D2R(r) ((r)/180.0*M_PI)

void berechnung_all(double a, double b, double c, double gamma,
    double *length, double *alpha, double *beta) {

  *length = sqrt(a * a + b * b - (2 * a * b * cos(D2R(gamma))));

  // Avoid direct call to `acos()`: prevent `double` math oddities just outside [-1.0...1.0]
  double x = (b * b + c * c - a * a) / (2.0 * b * c);
  if (x > 1.0) x = 1.0;
  if (x < -1.0) x = -1.0;
  *alpha = R2D(gamma * acos(x));

  #define TOTAL_DEG  (180.0)
  *beta = - gamma - alpha + TOTAL_DEG;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have an enumeration for the different operations and switch on that `enum` to perform different operations in your versatile function. Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TOTAL_DEG  (180.0)

enum oper {LENGTH, ALPHA, BETA};

double berechnung_any(double a, double b, double c, double gamma, enum oper op)
{   
    double retVal;
    switch(op) {
       case LENGTH: 
        retVal = sqrt(a * a + b * b - (2 * a * b * cos(gamma)));
       break;
       case ALPHA:
        retVal = gamma * acos((double )(b * b + c * c - a * a) / (2.0 * b * c));
       break;
       case BETA:
        retVal = - gamma - (gamma * acos((double )(b * b + c * c - a * a) / (2.0 * b * c))) + TOTAL_DEG;
       break;
   }
   return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, so i am assuming you already have variables a,b in hand and you don't have c, alpha and beta, but you want to have them after the calculation.
here is the code, i added a main function to demonstrate u how to use pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TOTAL_DEG  (180.0)

//here a and b are transferred by values, c, gamma and alpha are just pointers.
double berechnung_func(double a, double b, double* c, double* gamma, double* alpha){

    *c = sqrt(a * a + b * b - (2 * a * b * cos(*gamma)));
    *alpha = (*gamma) * acos((double )(b * b + (*c) * (*c) - a * a) / (2.0 * b * (*c)));

    return (- (*gamma) - (*alpha) + TOTAL_DEG);
}

int main()
{
    double c, gamma, alpha, beta, a=5, b=6;

    // here we are sending c, gamma and alpha **addresses** to the function.
    beta = berechnung_func(a, b, &c, &gamma, &alpha); 
    printf("c = %d\n gamma = %d\n alpha = %d\n beta = %d\n", c, gamma, alpha, beta);

    return 0;
}
```